# Could not find API definition for name "JDO"

Tags: java, mysql, mysqlconnector

При запуске из IDE (IntelliJ Idea) все работает, но после компиляции и упаковки в jar получаю ошибку Could not find API definition for name "JDO".
Использую maven с shade плагином.
[Зависимости проекта](https://pastebin.com/uCRjRKFN) [Сам код](https://pastebin.com/crcZgNnZ) [Стактрейс](https://pastebin.com/z8rMaW7d) [Итоговый jar](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IjRRyxV3ariT31CU-EOTvoRpDFCe9aPt/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Пакет jdo есть в итоговом jar?

Comment: да, есть, все содержимое datanucleus-api-jdo

Comment: Stacktrace тоже неплохо бы выложить.

Comment: все добавил, ссылки в теме

Comment: Попробуйте datanucleus-core 5.2.0-m2.

Comment: Попробовал, не помогло